SQLite 3: Sum a column and also show last value
I have found some similiar question but all have different requierements and cant figure out how to change them to my needs.
So I have this table:
Name      Value     Year
------------------------
John      5         2021
John      10        2022
John      6         2023
Kat       20        2021
Kat       10        2022
Kat       12        2023  

Expected result:
Name      Total     LastYear
----------------------------
Kat       42        12
John      21        6

Of course easy part for the first two is:
select name, sum(value) as Total from names group by name order by sum(value) desc

but how am I able to get the last one?
I tried union all, subselect (select value from names where year = 2023), nothing comes out how I want it to. ( the 2023 will replaced by a variable ofc)
Thanks for the help

Here are two options in the same sql:
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :  
Create Table tbl AS
Select 'John' as a_name,  5 as a_value,  2021 as a_year Union All
Select 'John',      10,        2022  Union All
Select 'John',      6,         2023  Union All
Select 'Kat',       20,        2021  Union All
Select 'Kat',       10,        2022  Union All
Select 'Kat',       12,        2023;

--      S Q L : 
Select   t.a_name, Sum(t.a_value) as Total,
         LAST_VALUE(t.a_value) Over(Partition By t.a_name Order By t.a_year) as last_year_1, 
         Max(Case When a_year = Cast(StrFTime('%Y', Date('now')) as Int) - 1  Then a_value End) as last_year_2
From     tbl t
Group By a_name
Order By a_name;

R e s u l t :



a_name
Total
last_year_1
last_year_2




John
21
6
6


Kat
42
12
12



fiddle
For some unknown reason the above code works as is - but the LAST_VALUE() without following Max() column gives faulty result. Thanks choroba for noticing and commenting...
So here are both codes separately that works ok ...
... with just normal aggregation
Select   t.a_name, Sum(t.a_value) as Total, 
         Max(Case When a_year = Cast(StrFTime('%Y', Date('now')) as Int) - 1  Then a_value End) as last_year_1
From     tbl t
Group By a_name
Order By a_name;

... OR with just analytic functions (but with Distinct keyword) ...
Select   Distinct  
         t.a_name, Sum(t.a_value) Over(Partition By t.a_name) as Total,
         LAST_VALUE(t.a_value) Over(Partition By t.a_name Order By t.a_year
                                    Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Unbounded Following) as last_year_1
From     tbl t;

fiddle

Interestingly, if you remove the second solution, the first solution starts to give a wrong answer (no idea why).

@choroba It looks like a confusion caused by analytic function with normal aggregation and Group By.  It works when just analytic functions are used (but with windowing clause). See it here: https://dbfiddle.uk/TKBMTv-Z  This doesn't make sense - I'd expect an error if that is wrong, though - not a faulty fetch.

https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/de165f9509

Aggregates are evaluated ahead of analytic functions. As such the sql was effectively doing LAST_VALUE(ANY(x)). I agree, it should error instead of allowing a non-aggregate to be used (like mysql used to allow)

https://dbfiddle.uk/d5p4IVWr

SELECT DISTINCT
   name,
   SUM(value) OVER (
      PARTITION BY name
   ) 
      AS total,
   FIRST_VALUE(value) OVER (
      PARTITION BY name
          ORDER BY year DESC
   )
      AS last_value
FROM
   names;


You mean SUM(Value), not MAX(Year).

You can use the WITH clause to avoid subselects to make the query more readable:
WITH last_year AS (
    SELECT MAX(Year) AS Year
    FROM Names
), sum_all AS (
    SELECT Name, SUM(Value) AS Value
    FROM Names
    GROUP BY Name
) SELECT names.Name,
         sum_all.Value AS Total,
         names.Value
    FROM last_year
        JOIN names ON last_year.Year = names.Year
        JOIN sum_all
        ON names.Name = sum_all.Name

